# Eigenvalues of block matrix where blocks are related

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues of following block matrix $A$ in terms of eigenvalues of matrix $B$?

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4I-B & -B  \\ 
-B & 2I  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Where $B$ is square matrix of order $n$ and $I$ is an identity matrix of order $n$

I have tried the following

let ,$w=\begin{bmatrix}
v \\ cv
\end{bmatrix}$ be an eigenvector of $A$ then with eigenvalue $\lambda_a$

then $Aw=\lambda_a w$

$\Rightarrow$
$4v-Bv-c(Bv)=\lambda_av$ and

$-Bv+2cv=\lambda_a(cv)$

$\Rightarrow$
$4v-\lambda_bv-c(\lambda_bv)=\lambda_av$

$-\lambda_b v+2cv=\lambda_a(cv)$

As $v$ is nonzero vector

$4-\lambda_b-c\lambda_b=\lambda_a$ and

$-\lambda_b+2c=c \lambda_a$

Now solving both the equation to find $c$.

Please verify whether my steps are correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: look at the vector 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v\\
cv
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $c$ is some constant. Under what condition on $c$ is this an eigenvector for your matrix?

Comment: i don't get that.Please answer in brief if its possible for you

Comment: I *did* answer in brief. When you show us the work you've done so far, I might consider amplifying my remarks a little.

Comment: I had written what I tried.Please verify and give your valuable comment on it

Comment: That looks pretty good. Multiply your first equation by $c$, and then subtract to eliminate the $c\lambda_a$ term. Now you've got a quadratic in $c$ to solve. Go for it!

Comment: BTW:  Note that by multiplying by $c$, you may introduce a false root of $c = 0$, and you'll have to check this. When you've got a solution for $c$, you get that $\lambda_a = 4 - \lambda_b - c\lambda_b$; with these values of $c$, you've therefore discovered two eigenvectors of $A$ for each eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Its done.But,I want to know how did you identified that $\begin{bmatrix} v \\ cv \end{bmatrix}$ will be eigenvector.What is the secrete behind it?

Comment: The secret is mostly "experience," alas. But look at the second row of B. If you think about $[v, v]$, it'll *almost* be an eigenvector: multiplying by $B$ will get you a factor of $\lambda$, multiplying by $2I$ will get you a $2$, but all in all, you'll still have a multiple of $v$. On the other hand, multiplying the first row of $B$ by the vector will "almost" preserve $v$ as well. But they do so by different factors..so throwing in a degree of freedom seemed as if it might work.